# How to sort DataFrame by string column with repeating values based on own idea of sort in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, sorting

I have DataFrame in Python Pandas like below:

```
COL1  | COL2 | ...  | COLn
------|------|------|-------
aaa   | AA_x | ...  | ...
bbb   | AA_x |  ... | ...
ggg   | AA_x |  ... | ...
ppp   | AA_x |  ... | ...
aaa   | DD_x |  ... | ...
ggg   | DD_x | ...  |  ...
ppp   | DD_x |  ... | ...
bbb   | DD_x |  ... | ...
....  | ...  | ...  | ...
```

**COL1 is string data type**, and I need to sort above DataFrame based values in COL1 on my own idea like: `aaa,bbb,ppp,ggg`, so as a result I need something like below:

```
COL2   | COL1  | ...   | COLn
-------|-------|-------|------
AA_x   | aaa   | ...   | ...
AA_x   | bbb   | ...   | ...
AA_x   | ppp   | ...   | ...
AA_x   | ggg   | ...   | ...
DD_x   | aaa   | ...   | ...
DD_x   | bbb   | ...   | ...
DD_x   | ppp   | ...   | ...
DD_x   | ggg   | ...   | ...
...    | ....  |  ...  |...
```

How can I do that in Python Pandas ? I assume that manually shout be sorted this DataFrame ?

Comment: How is the distribution in col1? If there aren't many different values, you can sort by assigning an id column. (like ppp=1, aaa=2)

Comment: Could you present your solution on samples of code ? I will check that on my real data frame, but distribution is like I presented In question, each value aaa, bbb and so on exists a few time, but i would like to sort that DF based on my idea from question :)

Comment: Clenge, there aren't many different values, can you show sample code how to sort by assinging an id column, please ?

Comment: How do you decide which `aaa` is first?

Comment: mozway, we could assume that based on "COL2" which I do not mention in question, so firstly sort by COL2 (string ascending = True), secondly sort by COL1 which I mentiond in question by my idea of sort so aaa,bbb,ppp,ggg, do yo uhave any solution, please ? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you want to sort by COL1 and keep the original order of the relative aaa/bbb/etc.

You can use:

```
order = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ppp', 'ggg']

df['COL1'] = pd.Categorical(df['COL1'], categories=order, ordered=True)

out = (df.assign(n=df.groupby('COL1').cumcount())
         .sort_values(by=['n', 'COL1'])
         .drop(columns='n')
       )
```

If you already have a secondary column to use to sort (eg. COL2):

```
order = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ppp', 'ggg']

df['COL1'] = pd.Categorical(df['COL1'], categories=order, ordered=True)

out = df.sort_values(by=['COL2', 'COL1'])
```

Comment: mozway, I edited my question, could you see that, i think that now is more clear :)

Comment: I already edited my answer

Comment: Hmm, I trid to use the first one code, and unfortunately it does not sort and moreover values from COL1 changed to NaN, what is wrong mozway ?

Comment: Have you tried with the provided example? You need to define `order` with the complete list of potential values of COL1.

Comment: Also, given your update you want the second code, not the first

Comment: mozway, ok I found error in my code, now everything works, thank, best answer given :)